# iOS 7 Viewcontroller not rotating when alertview is present

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7

iOS 7 Viewcontroller Not rotating when alertview  is present .

but my status bar is changing to orientation of the device . But view remains freezes at last orientation in which alert was present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have conflicting rotational code for any of the following methods?

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
```